# AngularJS controller with variable (possibly services)

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a stupid-simple html-ad generator to try and teach myself Angular. I know there is a better way to do this... (service/factory?) but I've racked my brain for a few hours and can't wrap my head around it.

I want an input for a URL and a dropdown-list for pre-existing ads. The result should be output to a textarea with the updated url. Instead, the `{{data.url}}` view helper thingamajig isn't replaced. Is this a $scope issue? do I need to somehow pass a param for the url? Is this a better job for a service--I tried to convert to service, but nothing "clicked" in terms of my understanding.

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="AdsCtrl">

  <label for="url">URL:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.url">

    <select ng-model="selected_ad" ng-options="ad.title for ad in ads">
      <option value="">Choose an ad:</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <textarea ng-model="selected_ad.ad"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('AdsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('ads.json')
    .then(function(res){
      $scope.ads = res.data;
    });
});
```

Ad example (json):

```
  {
    "title": "Business Development",
    "ad": "Go crazy making money...<br><br>Aren&apos;t you tired of being broke...<br><br>Learn all you can about making money from us...<br><br>This won&apos;t take much time at all...<br><br>To learn more <a href=\"{{data.url}}\">Click Here</a>"
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** to clarify, I'm trying to pass a variable (a user-provided URL) into a json string. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm a little lost at where the `data.url` is coming from?

Comment: @tymeJV I'm with you on that also where is `data.url` coming from ?

Comment: Well, I'm attempting to set it with the ng-model directive on an input. The problem is that's not working.

Comment: Hang on you set the directive inside your json on a `<a href>` is this is even possible?

Comment: I set the directive inside an `<input ng-model="data.url" />`, or at least I tried. It doesn't appear to be possible.

My question is how the heck do I do it? I'm guessing a service is the best way, but I can't quite imagine what it would look like.

Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: So you want your input from `<input ng-model="data.url" />` to replace the following `<a href=\"{{data.url}}\">` in your JSON file correct?

Comment: That's it precisely, David. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly bind to it without compiling the html in the ad as a view.  A much easier way, and with less dependencies, is to just do the replacement yourself.

Add this function to the scope inside your controller.

```
$scope.getSelectedAdSnippet = function (){
  var selectedAd = $scope.selected_ad || { ad: '' };
  var replacementUrl = $scope.replacementUrl || '';
  var transformedAd = selectedAd.ad.replace('{{data.url}}', replacementUrl);
  return transformedAd;
};
```

And change your view a little bit.

```
<div ng-controller="AdsController">

  <label for="url">URL:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="replacementUrl" />

  <select ng-model="selected_ad" ng-options="ad.title for ad in ads">
    <option value="">Choose an ad:</option>
  </select>

  <div>
    {{ getSelectedAdSnippet() }}
  </div>

</div>
```

Now you have something that will do the replacement for you.  Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMSfBECTU6ZeQnUHV1Us?p=preview) I cooked up for you.

Binding the textarea works as a 2 way binding that lets the user change the value of the ad code on your model.  This would require some real sorcery in order to have it work like I think you're after, so I opted for just displaying the value in the div.  You can use a fixed font to make it look more code like.

Comment: Awesome, Nick. I suspected "nested binding" wasn't possible, I just wasn't sure what best practice was for working around that limitation.